# Why does the spring boot maven plugin require a main class to package war?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

The **Spring Boot** guides give code that creates runnable **jars**, but we can use it build **war** files too as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file). Basically, it requires us to specify the packaging as war, remove the embedded tomcat server dependency, and extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer` class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

My question is that why do we need to provide a main method too, since the main method should only be required if we want to run a jar.

I tried to remove this main method and the compilation failed saying that the plugin couldn't find the main class.

Answer (score 3):

From that same page (11.3.3):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application-main-method

The final part of our application is the main method. This is just a standard method that follows the Java convention for an application entry point. Our main method delegates to Spring Boot’s SpringApplication class by calling run. SpringApplication bootstraps our application, starting Spring, which, in turn, starts the auto-configured Tomcat web server. We need to pass Example.class as an argument to the run method to tell SpringApplication which is the primary Spring component. The args array is also passed through to expose any command-line arguments.

Further information about `public static void main` and its relationship to `ServletContainerInitializer`:

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-serve-dynamic.html

Why SpringBootServletInitializer should be subclassed?
For producing a deployable war file, we have to provide a SpringBootServletInitializer subclass and override its configure method.

... The main class is extending SpringBootServletInitializer which in turn extends WebApplicationInitializer. WebApplicationInitializer is based on servlet 3.0 ServletContainerInitializer concept. **The purpose of this extension is: WebApplicationInitializer sets up servlet context and additionally it asks subclass to set up the source (the class annotated with @SpringBootApplication) of the SpringApplication, so that it can call SpringApplication#run() with a valid source and can do its auto configuration and application level bean wiring etc. This arrangement is only needed when application is deployed in a servlet container as a war file.** In a web container of course 'main method' can't get executed like it does in a stand-alone exploded application or executable jar or war.

Comment: There is neither an auto-configured Tomcat server, nor are we running the application through *java -jar*. Why do we need that main class?

Comment: The Maven plugin is designed to work alongside Spring Boot. Spring Boot assumes the existence of a `public static void main` method because part of Spring Boot's stated intentions is to make getting started with your app easier. The Maven plugin therefore requires a main method to be available, which is invoked to initialise the Spring application context, among other things. It doesn't matter whether you're running using java -jar, you still need to initialise the Spring framework. What makes you say "there is no auto-configured Tomcat server" - how are you deploying this application?

Comment: To further explain what I mean by "getting started with your app easier", Spring Boot allows you to create executable WARs. These are WARs with a `public static void main` method, and an entry in the MANIFEST.MF of the WAR pointing to that method.

Comment: *What makes you say "there is no auto-configured Tomcat server"* - I am specifying the tomcat dependency as *provided*. Perhaps the answer to my question is your suggestion that an executable WAR is created by default, and as such, a main class is required

Comment: @daud I believe the explanation may be in the section of my answer that I've just highlighted.

Comment: i am unable to figure out how the highlighted section explains why the main **method** is required. There seems only to be the need for a class that implements *SpringBootServletInitializer*

Comment: I believe its implied because of the `SpringBootApplication` annotation is placed on a class with the main method, containing the `SpringApplication#run`